chmod per file in the Samba shared directory
Is it possible to to set the individual file permissions in mounted samba shared filesystem?
The samba server is installed on a linux os (Debian 12, Raspberry Pi) and the shared volume is pointing to a directory in ext4.
If not possible is there an alternative to achieve this?

If it is possible to do in SAMBA its not trivial due to the way permissions work.   What is the source device/file system?   If its a NAS you may be able to use NFS instead - NFS can preserve file permissions.

Just like in windows, you should be setting your SMB/SAMBA permissions on the server, not the client. what specific problem are you having?

The samba server is installed on a linux os (Debian 12, Raspberry Pi) - (I have added it to the main question)

Let's suppose for simplicity a kind of one man show for the beginning. With this, I would like to achieve that the file attributes at the samba server (ext4 fs) can be resembled on a client 1:1 per file). Next time (optionally) we can suppose several users belonging to  one group and it will be able to set group attributes per individual file. Is it feasible via samba? If not, is it feasible via NFS?  (and if implemented via NFS, is it possible to consume the shared directory from windows clients too?)
